# Group some digits separately using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I need to parse strings using regular expressions having the following example configuration:

```
A1B135
W43T1236
```

I need to have the digits in separate groups for those digits at the end of the string.

So for A1B135:

```
group A
group 1
group B
group 1
group 3
group 5
```

But the digits in between the 2 letters must come out in a single group

So for W43T1236:

```
group W
group 43
group T
group 1
group 2
group 3
group 6
```

Comment: If the string can be arbitrarily large, then I don't believe this can be done.  See: [Repeating a Capturing Group vs. Capturing a Repeated Group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html).

Comment: Thanks this link is already very helpful. Fortunately this would not be arbitrarily large. 1 letter followed by max 2 digits, then 1 letter and then max 7 digits.

Comment: `([A-Z])(\d{0,2})([A-Z])(\d{0,7})`

Answer (score 2):

I think a lookahead (?=stuffThatShouldFollow) is what you need.

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
        String line = "W43T1236";
        String pattern = "([A-Z]|[0-9]+(?=.*[A-Z])|[0-9])";

        // Create a Pattern object
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        // Now create matcher object.
        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
    }

}
```

output:

```
W
43
T
1
2
3
6
```

Comment: Why? A simple pattern as [`([A-Z])(\d{0,2})([A-Z])(\d{0,7})`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503101/group-some-digits-separately-using-regular-expression#comment47166447_29503101) suffices

Comment: @hjpotter92, if all input data follows the provided pattern, then a simpler expression would work.  I couldn't tell from the question, so I provided an answer that works for the example as well as strings like "A12B34C5678D123".  I also believe that the last capture group in the pattern you provided would not separate the digits as `(\d)+` would.

Comment: "_Fortunately this would not be arbitrarily large. 1 letter followed by max 2 digits, then 1 letter and then max 7 digits_" +1 for the answer though

Comment: ah, you are a more perceptive comment reader than I.  I was wondering what you were quoting and just saw that :)

Comment: It can be rewritten as `\d++(?=[A-Z])|[A-Z\d]` or `[0-9]++(?=[A-Z])|[A-Z0-9]`. Take from capturing group 0